# How to read FAT Table in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, disk, interrupt, fat, floppy

NC - Norton Commander
I should write a program like NC.
I need to access Fat Table in Assembly to show files and directories in my program.
Does anybody know how I can access Fat in assembly( both floppy and Hard Disk )
What Interrupts should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you planning to load the resultant code from an operating system (in which case which one) or are you planning to try to boot it from the boot sector of a removable media?

Comment: Are you sure you want to _access FAT_ (directly), or you want to just get the list of directory entries, etc., in which case e.g. DOS services 4Fh, 4Eh under INT 21h will come handy?

Comment: If you've no OS, you're probably stuck with [int 13h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D02h:_Read_Sectors_From_Drive) (wow, that takes me back)

Comment: I just want to get the list of files and directories entries. I thought maybe I should access Fat directly i don't know what i should do ( in ms dos )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the FAT is protected by the OS for security reasons, so I guess you can't read/write it. You can still use the [interrupt #21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html) (3D - open, 3E - close, 3F - read, 40 - write, 42 - seek, 4E - find first file, 4F - find next file) or the [interrupt #13h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H).

- Int 13h is for low level disk services, so you can directly read or write any (I think) hard disk's (and floppy's) sector you want (functions 2 and 3).
- Int 21h allows you more high level file operations (some of which are listed above). Find first file and first next file find files that match a certain search pattern (just like windows's find, so you can list all files whose name is "*ab?c*.e?d"). I'm not sure if these functions list the directories too, you should check

Comment: Thanks , that was really helpful. I don't use Windows , I use MSDos 6.22 in Virtual Machine. How can I get the directory lists?

Comment: @ALi: prego! (you're welcome) :-)